# Speed up pandas operations

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running a operation over a pandas dataframe that contains a lot of rows so the operations are become too slow. I was wondering if there's a way to optimize it.
Let's say I have the next data on the dataframe:

```
         date        X
2019/5/1 10:00:00    1
2019/5/1 11:00:00    3
2019/5/1 12:00:00    5 
2019/5/1 13:00:00    2
2019/5/1 14:00:00    4 
2019/5/2 11:00:00    3
2019/5/2 12:00:00    2
```

What my code does is to check if for a given `x` on a row `i`, the value of `x` on the row `i-1` is bigger than the value of x on the row `i+1`as far as they are from the same row. the it creates a new column called `offset` where the value is `-1` where the previous statement is true, other wise is 0, and it also updates the date decreasing it 1 hour. The code:

```
for index, row in islice(df.iterrows(), 1, len(df.index)-1):
                if row.date.day == day:
                    if df.x[index-1] > df.x[index+1] or row.date.hour == 23:
                        df.offset[index] = -1
                        df.date[index] = df.date[index] - dt.timedelta(hours=1)
                else:
                    day = row.date.day
```

And the desired output would be this:

```
       date          X    offset
2019/5/1 10:00:00    1     0
2019/5/1 11:00:00    3     0
2019/5/1 11:00:00    5     -1
2019/5/1 12:00:00    2     -1
2019/5/1 14:00:00    4     0      <---Note that on this row, the next one is from a new day, so we dont use on comparision
2019/5/2 11:00:00    3     0
2019/5/2 11:00:00    2     -1
```

*Note the difference on the times.

This operations is taking something like 10 min on one file with around 15K rows and 4 columns. How could I speed it up?

Thanks

EDIT: forgot to mention. The rows need to be from the same day, other wise there's no comparison. Also, if the row is the last of the file or the last of the day (23:00:00) then the offset is always -1 because there's nothing to compare after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
# date column to datatime format
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
# compare with shifted version, 2 samples away
s = df.X.gt(df.X.shift(-2)).shift().fillna(False)
# turn series of booleans to 0s and -1s
df['offset'] = s.mul(-1)
# last sample in offset to -1
df.loc[df.shape[0]-1, 'offset'] -= 1
# subtract 1h using the same offset column
df.date += pd.to_timedelta(df.offset, unit='h')

       date            X    offset
0 2019-05-01 10:00:00  1       0
1 2019-05-01 11:00:00  3       0
2 2019-05-01 11:00:00  5      -1
3 2019-05-01 12:00:00  2      -1
4 2019-05-01 14:00:00  3       0
5 2019-05-02 11:00:00  5       0
6 2019-05-02 11:00:00  4      -1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works so so. It does not check the day. It would be the accepted answer if it would do exaclty the same but withi the same day.

Comment: @capie `and it also updates the date decreasing it 1 hour`, isn't this what it should do??

Comment: yes. The rows have a 1h step and we compare the values of `x` as far as the dates are within the same day. Check the example, i changed to fulfill this  last requirement. @yatu

Answer (score 1):

1. We mask the rows where the value of X a row above is greater than a row below.
2. We conditionally create our `offset` column where our mask is true we fill in `-1` else `0`
3. We do the same for our `date` column: where our mask is True, we subtract `1 hour`

```
m = df['X'].shift() > df['X'].shift(-1)

df['offset'] = np.where(m, -1, 0)
df['date'] = np.where(m, df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(1, 'hour'), df['date'])

                 date  X  offset
0 2019-05-01 10:00:00  1       0
1 2019-05-01 11:00:00  3       0
2 2019-05-01 11:00:00  5      -1
3 2019-05-01 12:00:00  2      -1
4 2019-05-01 14:00:00  3       0
5 2019-05-02 11:00:00  5       0
6 2019-05-02 12:00:00  4       0
```

**Notice** that on the last row there's no change because it cannot compare with a row underneath

Comment: Good approach, but I forgot to mention that they need to be only checked within  the same day